# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "tocado [de la cabeza]"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

En [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61620/why-is-the-term-touched-no-longer-commonly-used?rq=1) encontré una pregunta que me causó curiosidad. El post preguntaba por el origen de la expresión *touched in the head*, generalmente aplicada a personas no del todo mentalmente sanas, y más concretamente a autistas. Me resultó interesante porque en español existe la misma frase, “estar [algo] [tocado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Zvvw5YD|Zvw5a4i) [de la cabeza]”, cuya primera aparición en la literatura precede o coincide con la expresión inglesa. Según la pregunta mencionada, las primeras apariciones en inglés en la prensa escrita (considerando las limitaciones de Google Ngrams) podrían haber sido en las primeras décadas de 1700. Según el CORDE ([link 1](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll), [link 2](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll)), la primera aparición clara de la expresión en español que he podido encontrar es de 1654:

> “Han entrado por el Tortonés en el Estado de Milan 3.500 franceses, agregándoseles los modeneses, procurando invernar en aquel Estado, haciendo todo cuanto mal y daño pueden, y el Marqués de Caracena se dice está **algo tocado de la cabeza** y con cuartanas dobles, y que el de Mantua tomó la posta desde París y se ha metido en el Casal de Monferrato.”
>
> Barrionuevo, Jerónimo de (1654-1658). [*Avisos. Tomos I, II, III y IV.*](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=290416%5C016%5CC000O29042016161114348.1176.1172&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+tocado+de+la+cabeza%7B|I%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B|I%7D+%7B|B%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0) Antonio Paz y Melia, Imprenta de M. Tello (Madrid), 1892 - 1893

Podría ya existir [medio siglo antes](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=5&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=290416%5C016%5CC000O29042016161303882.1176.1172&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+algo+tocado+%7B|I%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B|I%7D+%7B|B%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto5), aunque no he encontrado ningún fragmento donde la expresión se refiera a estar loco o medio loco sin ninguna ambigüedad. La expresión “tocado” con el sentido de “afectado” sí aparece en fechas más antiguas:

> “El que piensa mal de su próximo, aunque calle su lengua, no está libre de pecado, delante de Dios es ya pecador; pero el que a cada propósito exercita su lengua contra el próximo ausente, entre los buenos varones es aborrecible y abominable. Porque cada uno teme el veneno de aquel escorpión, y aborresce al hombre que **está tocado desta enfermedad** aunque sepa que dize verdad, porque lo dize por vicio y no por razón, porque sabe que también dirá la mentira si a la memoria le viniesse.”
>
> Pérez de Chinchón, Bernardo (1533). [*La lengua de Erasmo nuevamente romançada por muy elegante estilo*](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=22&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=290416%5C016%5CC000O29042016164301796.1184.1180&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+est%E1+tocado%7B|I%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B|I%7D+%7B|B%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto22). Dorothy S. Severin, Real Academia Española (Madrid), 1975

Ya desde mediados del siglo XIV se encuentra con frecuencia acompañada de sentimientos, como [estar tocado de avaricia](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=30&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=290416%5C016%5CC000O29042016164301796.1184.1180&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+est%E1+tocado%7B|I%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B|I%7D+%7B|B%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto30) (1594), [de furor](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=34&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=290416%5C016%5CC000O29042016164301796.1184.1180&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+est%E1+tocado%7B|I%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B|I%7D+%7B|B%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto34) (1562), [de pasión](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=2&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=290416%5C016%5CC000O29042016164301796.1184.1180&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+est%E1+tocado%7B|I%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B|I%7D+%7B|B%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto2) (1587), [de celos](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=7&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=290416%5C016%5CC000O29042016164301796.1184.1180&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+est%E1+tocado%7B|I%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B|I%7D+%7B|B%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto7) (1602), [de tristeza](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=7&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=290416%5C016%5CC000O29042016164301796.1184.1180&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+est%E1+tocado%7B|I%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B|I%7D+%7B|B%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto7) (1575) o [de soberbia](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=21&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=290416%5C016%5CC000O29042016164301796.1184.1180&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+est%E1+tocado%7B|I%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B|I%7D+%7B|B%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto21) (1590), entre otros:

> “que éste es solo el Amor que permanece,
>   y no una afición vana que florece
>   en quien **de un tal amor está tocado**
>   que no pretende amar si no es amado.”
>
> Montemayor, Jorge de (1554 - 1559). [*Cancionero*](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=47&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=290416%5C016%5CC000O29042016164301796.1184.1180&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+est%E1+tocado%7B|I%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B|I%7D+%7B|B%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto47). Juan Bautista Avalle-Arce y Emilio Blanco, Turner (Madrid), 1996

En estas fechas también aparecen menciones a entidades divinas o fantásticas<sup>1</sup>:

> “Escriben del mirto que huele bien y que es tierno y delicado y todo parece que espira aquella gracia y regalo de Venus y que **está tocado de la deidad** de ella, y por eso consagrado a la misma Venus, a quien se atribuyó, o por una conciliación y naturaleza particular, o porque es planta marítima y Venus nació en el mar.”
>
> Herrera, Fernando de (1580). [*Comentarios a Garcilaso*](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=24&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=290416%5C016%5CC000O29042016164301796.1184.1180&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+est%E1+tocado%7B|I%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B|I%7D+%7B|B%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto24). Antonio Gallego Morell, Gredos (Madrid), 1972
>
> “Pues qué, si **está tocado de la musa**,
>   i no quiere llegar a las tabernas
>   su fama desdichada, como se usa,
>   no sólo a los desiertos i cavernas
>   lo condenan por bárbaro, mas creo
>   que penas le quisieran dar eternas.”
>
> Argensola, Lupercio Leonardo de (c 1579 - a 1613). [*Rimas*](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=45&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=290416%5C016%5CC000O29042016164301796.1184.1180&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+est%E1+tocado%7B|I%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B|I%7D+%7B|B%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto45). José Manuel Blecua, CSIC (Zaragoza), 1950

“Tocado” en el sentido de “dotado”, acompañado de cualidades positivas, parece haber aparecido algunos siglos más tarde:

> “El carácter de la madre es excelente y sostenido; el de Inés es delicado, tierno, profundo, **está tocado con una maestría encantadora**;”
>
> Larra, Mariano José de (1834). [*Representación de "La niña en casa y la madre en la máscara" comedia original de don Francisco Martí ...*](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=14&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=290416%5C016%5CC000O29042016164301796.1184.1180&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+est%E1+tocado%7B|I%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B|I%7D+%7B|B%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto14). Alejandro Pérez Vidal, Crítica (Barcelona), 2000
>
> “Destaca entre los que lo rodean porque **está tocado de una gracia** que surge raramente en los conjuntos urbanos de formación acelerada: la rúbrica de un arquitecto caro, idealista y autoritario.”
>
> Palomino, Ángel (1971). [*Torremolinos, Gran Hotel*](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=1&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=290416%5C016%5CC000O29042016164301796.1184.1180&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+est%E1+tocado%7B|I%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B|I%7D+%7B|B%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto1). Planeta (Barcelona), 1996

### Mi pregunta

En el post enlazado la respuesta más votada explica que *touched* en el sentido de “loco” proviene de la expresión *touched by God*. En la expresión española, el origen podría ser tanto “tocado (≈afectado) por alguna enfermedad mental” como “tocado (≈inspirado) por Dios o alguna deidad similar”.

- ¿Existe alguna evidencia de que “tocado” con el sentido de “loco” provenga de una u otra expresión?
- El verbo inglés proviene del francés [*tochier*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=touch), que proviene a su vez del verbo latín *toccare*, que nos ha dado en español “tocar”. ¿Existía la acepción de “perturbar” o “afectar” en el término latín, lo cual explicaría por qué las expresiones “tocado [de la cabeza]” y *touched [in the head]* significan ambas “loco”?
- Ambas expresiones aparecieron en momentos sorprendentemente cercanos en el tiempo (1650 y 1700, aproximadamente). ¿Existe algún motivo lingüístico/etimológico (por ejemplo, la aparición de la expresión en un idioma habría permitido su exportación al otro), o se trata tan solo de un artefacto metodológico (por ejemplo, los motores de búsqueda suelen tener un número relativamente escaso de obras anteriores a 1500)?

---

<sup>1: En ambos casos, el agente aparece introducido por la preposición “de” en lugar de “por”. Curiosamente, en italiano el agente va siempre introducido por *da*, y en francés puede ir introducido por *de* en algunos casos aunque la preposición más usual es *par*. Es plausible pensar que antiguamente el complemento de agente iba introducido por “de” aunque ahora esta forma ya haya quedado obsoleta (haré una pregunta al respecto en breve). En cualquier caso, es seguro interpretarla como “por” aquí.</sup>

Comment: En donde he buscado, encuentro el verbo latino como _*toccare_: el asterisco significa que no hay evidencia directa de su existencia (!), sino que sólo se ha reconstruido por su presencia en distintas lenguas romances. No es una conjetura descabellada que sea un _calco_ posterior, aunque los lingüistas tendrán sus razones (el DRAE dice que es una onomatopeya). [Esta página](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=touch) dice que _to touch_ (o *toccare?) tenía el sentido de _affect or move mentally or emotionally_ en el s.XIV: podría ser origen común de ambos significados (Dios o enf. mental).

Answer (score 4):

He estado investigando tu pregunta, y no he encontrado mucha información, pero lo que sí que he encontrado es:

- Tocar *no viene del latín,* sino de la onomatopeya *toc toc* -Según la RAE-. Según el [WIktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toccare), se piensa que el verbo en latín pudiera ser toccare, pero no hay evidencias de eso y se trata de una reconstrucción.

-Dicho esto, en mi opinión simplemente se trata de un aumento del significado de la palabra. Según la RAE, la definición número 10 de esa palabra es

> 10. tr. Alterar el estado o condición de algo.

- Creo que este es el significado que toma el verbo en estos casos, y está relacionado con cómo al "tocar" algo, lo estás modificando: ya no es igual que antes de tocarlo. Por supuesto esto sólo son conjeturas, y no he encontrado evidencia que soporte esto.
- Sin embargo, me pregunto si podría estar relacionado con el verbo Francés toquer que significa "golpear", "atacar". Echa un vistazo a la expresión [Touche](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch%C3%A9) también, que viene del francés, se refiere a la esgrima, y que  curiosamente empezó a aparecer en el año XVII también.

> Touché: La expresión probablemente viene de los primeros duelos,
>   comunes en el siglo XVII: durante el duelo, tocar al opositor con la
>   punta desto pasaba el perdedor podía reconocer la derrota gritando
>   «tocado» y entonces el encuentro terminaba.

Answer (score 2):

Una expresión similar que puede estar relacionada es tocado del ala. Este ala probablemente se refiere al ala de un sombrero. [He encontrado](http://www.esacademic.com/dic.nsf/sp_sp_dichos_refranes/1061/estar) la siguiente explicación:

> **Tocado del ala**
>
> estar tocado del ala Estar loco. La explicación hay que analizarla a
>   partir de la expresión estar tocado del ala. **Ala** es la parte del
>   sombrero que rodea la copa y que cae sobre las sienes. Cuando queremos
>   dar a entender que alguien no está muy bien de la cabeza, nos tocamos
>   o barrenamos la sien. Quienes llevaban sombrero, lo hacían en el ala.

Probablemente tocado [de la cabeza] tenga un origen o una explicación similar.

Answer (score 2):

Isaac Asimov especula lo siguiente:

> Cuando un hombre enfermaba, los antiguos decían que estaba poseído por un espíritu maligno, y la idea parecía especialmente certera cuando el afectado hacía y decía cosas incoherentes. Como nadie actuaría así por propia voluntad, la gente lo atribuía al «demonio que llevaba dentro». Por eso, las sociedades primitivas trataban a veces al enfermo mental con sumo respeto y cuidado. **El loco era alguien que había sido tocado por el dedo de un ser sobrenatural** (y hoy seguimos utilizando la palabra «tocado» para describir a un individuo que parece no estar en sus cabales).

En *Grandes Ideas de la Ciencia*, capítulo 12: [*Hipócrates y la Medicina*](http://www.librosmaravillosos.com/grandesideasdelaciencia/capitulo12.html).

Comment: ¡Interesante link! También explica una vía a través de la cual la expresión puede haber llegado a distintas lenguas.